# How do I make Item Notifier for Website in Discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I am working on a Discord bot that will notify users about new Items that come on a certain site. The problem is I don't know how to do it. Is there any tutorials for that? I tried looking around the YT and Google but didn't find anything, I was maybe unlucky.

I tried to make it copy items name but it just didn't work. Is there any other ways of doing it?

There is no code for that part. I am just looking to the video or site where I can find the tutorial.

Nothing here too.

Comment: Do you control the other site? It sounds like this may be more suited to a webhook rather than a full discord bot.

Comment: No, I don't control it. I just want to make something like "RBXNotifier" which says when some items get published for other people to buy.

Comment: You probably want to make a webscraper that gathers the information of any new items, and then uses a webhook to post a message to discord. Your first step should probably be to forget the discord component for now and build a webscraper that can get the new items form the website.

Comment: I just started that project, completely forgot about it. I will try to do WebScraping :) Thanks for help though.